# How to use template in PrimeNG panelMenu

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to add some html code in menu entries so I try to use  to custom the display :

My template :

```
<p-panelMenu styleClass="main-menu" class="main-menu" [model]="menus">
    <ng-template let-menus pTemplate>
        {{menus.label}} <span>otherStuff</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-panelMenu>
```

The component :

```
this.menus = [
        {
          label: 'Dashboard',
          icon: 'fa-home',
          routerLink: '/home'
        },
    ...
```

Nothing happen and it still display the menu as if I didn't add the template. What do I miss?

Comment: Would it be possible to have a demo?

Comment: Can you check my answer. i think this way to add template in panelMenu

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find a way to do it? Share it plaese if you found.

Comment: Yes, finally I concatenate menu.label and 'otherStuff' in the .ts like that : label: `${label} (${count})`,

Answer (score 2):

As of the current implementation, you can't. One option is to override the component and add that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use  inside the p-panelMenu so try below like this :

**try this :**

```
<p-panelMenu styleClass="main-menu" class="main-menu" [model]="menus">
</p-panelMenu>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    menus: MenuItem[];

    constructor(
    ) {

        this.menus = [{
            label: 'Dashboard',
            icon: 'fa-home',
            routerLink: '/home'
        }]
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let element1 = document.createElement('span')
        let element2 = document.createTextNode('otherStuff');
        element1.appendChild(element2)
        let d1 = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-menuitem-text')[0].appendChild(element1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will work but I would like to avoid manipulating the DOM